# Why is the C++ std library not inherently thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I understand that, fundamentally, using classes in C++ aren't thread-safe because their functions aren't atomic and this can lead to race conditions.

While learning to write multithreaded programs in a class, we had to wrap critical sections where an object was being read/written from in mutexes in order to ensure atomicity. Having spent time reading through a bit of the standard library, I was curious why C++ doesn't do this automatically for a user.

My understanding is that a mutex only contains within it a boolean or integer that represents the state of the lock as well as some form of a queue that represents all the threads waiting on the lock. Seeing as this is not a significant amount of overhead, why doesn't the standard library automatically provide this abstraction and wrap all of its functions with a mutex local to only that class (i.e. not a global mutex)?

Comment: Why would all the folk not using threads want to pay the overhead of thread safety?

Comment: Where does thread safety begin and end, and what really needs to be safe? The classic example is the Java `Vector` which has been on the do not use list for about a quarter century because it tries to be thread safe without considering that thread-safe operations are rarely as important as thread safe transactions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the only overhead of an inherent mutex would be a single integer and empty queue, would the overhead be significant enough to matter at anything beyond very large inputs?

To your second point, what's the difference between a thread-safe operation and thread-safe transaction? @user4581301

Comment: Storage-wise the cost might be low. Performance wise its often lethal. Everything has to stop and acquire the mutex and then release it. That may be fast, but it'll add up very quickly if everything has to do it. For something like the Standard library you have to service the lowest common denominator, the stuff everybody needs, because if you build in costs that service only some of the people, only those people will use the library.

Comment: Thread safety comes at the application level. You can’t just lump together a bunch of thread safe objects and get a thread safe application. `if (!container.is_empty()) container.do_something_with_first_element();` can crash and burn if the container is accessed from multiple threads, even if every operation on the container is thread safe. Some other thread can remove the last element between this code’s test and its attempt to use it.

Comment: Say you need to get ten values from a container and sum them. You have ten fetch operations and one write. In a thread-safe transaction, there is one lock then all ten values are acquired and summed, the result stored and the section is unlocked. If the operations are thread safe, each value read from the container has a lock and an unlock and other values in the container may be changed between them, ruining the snapshot of all ten guaranteed by the transaction. The summation may require nine more locks and unlocks and storing the result may require another lock and unlock.

Comment: This approach is losing performance all over the place and may may not even deliver the results you needed because values were changed while the data was being collected.

Comment: And let's not forget about embedded systems, where even the storage cost would matter. Adding extra `int`  (or likely a pointer because padding) to every `std::unique_ptr` would mean we would have to write our own version of it, and the same with every other standard library class. Our own classes would likely be less efficient and worse for optimisation, so we'd eventually have to revert to C to keep the size and speed...

Comment: Even in a _multithreaded_ program, you don't want every function you call to be "thread safe." You only need thread safety when accessing data that actually are shared between threads. It would be a performance killer if every thread had to acquire and release locks to access all of its own _private_ variables.

Comment: Ensuring thread safety costs.   There are performance impacts at run time, coding is more complicated (easier to get things wrong, significantly more effort to debug).    Making the standard library thread safe wouldn't necessarily make programs thread-safe.   A lot of software doesn't need thread safety, so forcing the everything in the standard library to be thread safe imposes a cost that is unnecessary.    Also, before C++11, the C++ standard did not support multithreading at all (multithreading was achieved using system-specific extensions).

Comment: *Why is the C++ std library not inherently thread safe?*  Because that would go against the primary goal:  performance.

Comment: @zalanshah64 *I was curious why C++ doesn't do this automatically for a user* -- This goes against the [zero overhead principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle#:~:text=The%20zero%2Doverhead%20principle%20is,could%20reasonably%20write%20by%20hand.) of C++.  Why not also ask why C++ doesn't introduce automatic array bounds checking?  For the same reason thread-safety isn't automatic.

Comment: This is the tradeoff for having power and flexibility.If you want thread safe, write or use thread safe functions / classes. If you don't need thread safe, you don't lose performance.

This doesn't just apply to thread safety, it applies to everything in C++.

This is why there are different programming languages and frameworks. One size does not fit all.

Comment: The mantra of C++ is `Don't pay for what you don't use`. And in a lot of cases thread saftety is not required. And on top of that thread safety can be modeled in a lot of ways and you need to pick the approach that best fits yourusecase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even ignoring the question of performance (which is a lot to ignore), thread safety is *never* as simple as "all objects have a mutex in them."

Let's say you have a thread-safe container. There's a container object that gets shared. So, is this code "thread-safe":

```
shared_container.push_back(value1);
shared_container.push_back(value2);
```

Well, that depends: if the intent of this code is that `value1` and `value2` are adjacent to one another, no, that behavior is not guaranteed. The literal text will not cause a data race, but it will not have the desired behavior either.

The purpose of code is to do what it says. Failure to do that is a bug, whether it's because of a data race or a violation of the desired behavior of the code.

And what about this:

```
shared_container.emplace_back(param1, param2);
```

Remember: `emplace_back` calls a constructor (of the container's element type) within the function call. What happens if that constructor tries to access `shared_container`? You can't lock the object on a different thread.

Or even better, what happens if that constructor needs to access some other shared object, but the thread holding the lock on that object is blocked waiting on `shared_container`'s lock? Which your thread owns and cannot release because you're in the middle of `emplace_back`?

You cannot have functioning multithreading and not think about thread safety. You can compartmentalize inter-thread communication, but you can never just not think about it. Making all objects "thread-safe" by default only provides the illusion of safety. What's worse is that it makes it harder to track down bugs, because they're much more subtle.

We can even see an example from the standard library of more reasonable thread-safe thinking. `promise/future` is a means of forwarding a single object from one thread to another. But stripped down to its basic concept, you *could* think of it as just a "thread-safe" `optional<T>` that you share between threads.

But they aren't the same thing.

`promise/future` has an asymmetric interface. Once the code holding the `promise` sets the value, it *cannot* access or modify that value. The code holding the `future` cannot manipulate the value; they can only see if it has been set or access it. The interface says that there is a provider of the value and a receiver of the value, and that value can *only* go one way.

A shared `optional<T>` has no interface-level support for this kind of value forwarding. If you have access to the object, then you can set or get the value, as you see fit. But that's generally not how data management works across threads, and it's definitely a lot less "safe" compared to `promise/future`.

Safe inter-thread communication is best done by using objects specifically designed for doing so. Objects whose interface support a specific mode of inter-thread communication, ones which have very strict inter-thread interactions.